# TYPO3 Extbase: Assigning 2 different objects to the view?

Tags: typo3

I have a showAction in my Controller of the class "Termin" that not only assigns the object of that class to the view, but it should also pass a second object that is in relation to that object via the getter.

```
 public function showAction(\...\Kundentermine\Domain\Model\Termin $termin)
    {

        $this->view->assign('termin', $termin);
        $this->view->assign('kaufmnnisch', $termin->getZugewkaufmaennisch());


    }
```

The corresponding template should not only show details for the "Termin" object, but also have a link to the show action of another Controller which i pass the second assigned object "kaufmnnisch" to.

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <f:link.action  action="show" controller="Kaufmnnisch" arguments="{kaufmnnisch : kaufmnnisch}">
            <f:translate key="tx_kundentermine_domain_model_termin.kaufmaennisch" />
            </f:link.action>
            {termin.kaufmaennisch}

        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

But i get an error:

```
Argument 1 passed to ...\Kundentermine\Controller\KaufmnnischController::showAction() must be an instance of ...\Kundentermine\Domain\Model\Kaufmnnisch, null given
```

Why is the object NULL? Testing "$termin->getZugewkaufmaennisch()" inside a va_dump() within the TerminController gets me the correct object, so why isn't the object assigned to the view?

Edit: As requested, here is the show Action of the Controller "Kaufmnnisch" that gets the object $kaufmnnisch, which supposedly is NULL on arrival, so to speak.

```
  /**
     * action show
     *
     * @param \...\Kundentermine\Domain\Model\Kaufmnnisch $kaufmnnisch
     * @return void
     */
    public function showAction(\...\Kundentermine\Domain\Model\Kaufmnnisch $kaufmnnisch)
    {
        $this->view->assign('kaufmnnisch', $kaufmnnisch);
    }
```

Edit2: Problem solved...

The problem was that the object was assigned to the template, but from there it should have been passed to a partial as an argument. So it never arrived ath the point:

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <f:link.action  action="show" controller="Kaufmnnisch" arguments="{kaufmnnisch : kaufmnnisch}">
            <f:translate key="tx_kundentermine_domain_model_termin.kaufmaennisch" />
            </f:link.action>
            {termin.kaufmaennisch}

        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Now, after i added it here:

```
<f:render partial="Termin/Properties" arguments="{termin:termin, kaufmnnisch:kaufmnnisch}" />
```

It works flawlessly.

Comment: Could you please show us the second Controller that is called `KaufmnnischController`? Also, you should really write your code in english and avoid using other languages. It is easier for other coders to understand your code, if they are not capable of speaking german for example.

Comment: Is the inconsistency of `kaufmnnisch` vs. `kaufmaennisch` intentional?

Comment: I dropped the "ae" while creating the new model object in the extension_builder to make a destinction between "tx_kundentermine_domain_model_termin.kaufmaennisch" which is a boolean property of the class "Termin" and the class "Kaufmnnisch"